# Unittest multiple subclasses

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a code structure where we have a lot of sub classes from a common base class.
I want in an automated fashion test each subclass without having a separate class definition inheriting from `TestCase` for each subclass.

with a classs like

```py
class MyBaseClass:
    ...
```

I can get a list of all subclasses that inherits from `MyBaseClass` with

```py
import all_module_that_includes_subclasses

list_of_all_subclasses = MyBaseClass.__subclasses__()
```

But how do I connect to this list of scubclasses to avoid manually createing TestCases for each subclass like:

```py
class TestSubClass1(TestCase):
   def test_method_1(self):
      ...
   ...

class TestSubClass2(TestCase):
   def test_method_1(self):
      ...
   ...

etc.
```

I thought of setting up an instance of all classes in `setUp()` method and looping through them in each `def test_method_#()`. This will somewhat work, I think, but it will break as soon as one single class fails. I want to be able to run through all classes and get a full report what class failed and in what tests.

Thankful for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create those test cases dynamically using the [`load_tests`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol) protocol. For this you simply define a top-level function called `load_tests` which should return a [`TestSuite`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestSuite).

```py
import unittest


class MyBaseClass:
    pass


class Foo(MyBaseClass):
    pass


class Bar(MyBaseClass):
    pass


class TestBases:
    # Wrapped into other class, so it won't be discovered by unittest.
    class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
        subclass: MyBaseClass

        def test(self):
            self.assertIsInstance(self.subclass(), MyBaseClass)


def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    for cls in MyBaseClass.__subclasses__():
        test_cls = type(f'Test{cls.__name__}', (TestBases.TestCase,), dict(subclass=cls))
        tests.addTests(loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(test_cls))
    return tests


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This runs the two dynamically generated test cases `TestFoo` and `TestBar`:

```
$ python /tmp/test.py -v
test (__main__.TestFoo) ... ok
test (__main__.TestBar) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s
```

Comment: Thanks @a_guest, This helped me a lot and I got it working.
Some key things here that you wrote is actually the `type( ... )` command which dynamically creates the TestCases with correct subclass attached. [Ref](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_classes_and_type.php)
The way that you are using a wrapper and a base test class is a nice way as well. Thank you a lot!